# Retrieve most recent of multiple rows

Tags: mysql

Have asked this question several times, but never received an actual answer!

I have a table which looks like this:

```
answer_id  q_id  answer  qscore_id  answer_timestamp
1          10    Male    3          1363091016
2          10    Male    3          1363091017
3          11    Male    3          1363091018
4          10    Male    3          1363091019
5          11    Male    3          1363091020
6          12    Male    3          1363091020
7          11    Male    3          1363091025
```

So I have multiple answers for the same questions (q_id). I want to be able to retrieve only ONE answer per question and that be the most recent answer.

IE.

There should be THREE rows returned, which are all the most recent answered for that q_id:

```
4          10    Male    3          1363091019
6          12    Male    3          1363091020
7          11    Male    3          1363091020
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @tombom why rejected my suggested revision?

Comment: I didn't reject anything?

Comment: Oooops so somebody as Community did! http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1707149

Comment: Also it's pretty clear, that this data is just an example. It's the case in almost every question here on SO. So please refrain from adding such info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subselect to get the max timestamps and then join that back against the table

```
SELECT a.answer_id, a.q_id, a.answer, a.qscore_id, a.answer_timestamp
FROM SomeTable a
INNER JOIN (SELECT q_id, MAX(answer_timestamp) AS answer_timestamp FROM SomeTable GROUP BY q_id) Sub1
ON a.q_id = Sub1.q_id AND a.answer_timestamp = Sub1.answer_timestamp
```

Answer (score -2):

select * from table where q_id=? order by  answer_timestamp desc limit 3

Comment: That will simply give me the three most recently answered questions - not the most recently answered for the three individual questions.